# Adding annotations at runtime (android)

Tags: android, annotations, runtime

I want to annotate a list of methods dynamically at runtime, i'm asking if is it possible to do that,i tried and read a lot of things like byte buddy ,ASM,java reflection,javaassist(work just for java) none of them works for me we can just use them to create,customize and get annotations but not assign them at runtime, any suggestions please ?? 
Thanks